# Redondear números enteros en gráficos ggplot

Tags: r

Tengo un dataframe con dos decimales:

```
               GOLD         Veterinario       values    prop
               No Animal    Veterinario I   636     88.95
               Animal I     Veterinario I   49       6.85
               Animal II    Veterinario I   28       3.92
               Animal III   Veterinario I   2        0.28
               No Animal    Veterinario II  516     86.00
               Animal I     Veterinario II  52       8.67
               Animal II    Veterinario II  29       4.83
               Animal III   Veterinario II  3        0.50
```

He graficado el dataframe utilizando el siguiente código:

```
p<-p+
  theme(
    panel.grid.major = element_blank(), panel.grid.minor = element_blank(),
    panel.background = element_blank(),
    legend.text = element_text(face="bold"),
    legend.title = element_text(face="bold"),
    text=element_text(size=12),
    plot.title=element_text(face="bold",hjust=c(0,0)),
    axis.text.y = element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.text.x = element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.title.x = element_text(face="bold"),
    axis.title.y=element_blank()
  )+
  geom_text(
    aes(x = GOLD, y = prop, label = prop, group = Veterinario),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    vjust = -0.5, size = 4) +
  labs(x = "Gold Levels")+
  ylim(0,100)

figure<-ggarrange(
  p, common.legend = TRUE, legend = "bottom")


annotate_figure(figure,
                top = text_grob("Evolution of GOLD levels (last 10 years)", face = "bold", size =14))
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como podeis ver en el grupo No EPOC de Veterinario II aparece 86 porque es un número entero. Sin embargo yo tengo en el dataframe 86.00 y otros números con más de dos decimales ¿Cómo puedo cambiarlo para que el gráfico aparezca como números con solo dos decimales?

Gracias de antemano

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes formatear los números y pasarlos a una cadena mediante [`sprintf()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/sprintf) puedes hacer o no el redondeo, lo importante es el formato `%0.2f` que indica que se está recibiendo un numero de coma flotante con 2 decimales fijos:

```
 geom_text(
    aes(x = GOLD, 
        y = prop, 
        label = sprintf("%0.2f", round(prop, digits = 2)), 
        group = Veterinario),
    position = position_dodge(width = 1),
    vjust = -0.5, size = 4)
```

Comment: Funciona perfectamente, muchas gracias Patricio